# Laravel jordanmiguel/laravel-popular error

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel/popular and when I add 3 classes and migrate it gives me error. Here that 3 classes are listed:

```
JordanMiguel\LaravelPopular\LaravelPopularServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider:class,
```

[Laravel popular](https://github.com/jordanmiguel/laravel-popular)

**In Connection.php line 664:**

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key
>   was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes (SQL: alter table `visits`
>   add unique `visits_ip_visitable_id_visitable_type_date_unique`(`ip`,
>   `visitable_id`, `visitable_type`, `date`))

**In Connection.php line 458:**

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key
>   was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Answer (score 0):

In ur app\Providers\AppSErviceProvider.php file add these two lines:

at the top:
`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema`;

inside the boot function:

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

Updated:
After seeing ur comments its not working, u may need to run the below mysql query in your phpmyadmin (if u have access).

```
CREATE TABLE `visits` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `visitable_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `visitable_type` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `visits`
--
ALTER TABLE `visits`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `visits_ip_visitable_id_visitable_type_date_unique` (`ip`,`visitable_id`,`visitable_type`,`date`),
  ADD KEY `visits_ip_index` (`ip`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `visits`
--
ALTER TABLE `visits`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;COMMIT;
```

This will create the table for you, no need to run `php artisan migrate`
Its not the perfect answer but it solves your problem, temporarily.

Comment: I already added it sir @arun kumar

Comment: close ur terminal or putty then open again. if it didn't help, run 'composer dump-autoload'

Comment: still same :( . i tried cache:clear , dump-autoload . and still same error

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes (SQL: alter table `visits` add unique `visits_ip_visitable_id_visitable_type_d
  ate_unique`(`ip`, `visitable_id`, `visitable_type`, `date`))`

Comment: @М.Билгүүн, take a look at updated answer

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppServiceProvider`, add this line to boot method-

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Comment: i already added it sir

Comment: please add your migration file where you are having the error and what is your laravel version??

Comment: https://github.com/jordanmiguel/laravel-popular

Comment: Please check this out sir. i added 3 classes . and tried run migrate and it gives me error i dont have any migration file

Comment: you didn't change anything on this file, right??

Comment: no i didnt. is there any way to take site visit count, post visit count? im stuck in problem. and i found it

Comment: you could create a column in post table for count post visit and another table for site visit, what is your laravel version BTW??

Comment: my laravel version is 5.5

Comment: `If you're on Laravel <= 5.4 add 'JordanMiguel\LaravelPopular\LaravelPopularServiceProvider::class', in your config/app.php to the end of the $providers array`

Comment: my english is not good sir. im tried 2 ways. tried 3 of em once, and 1 of em once.

Comment: remove the first one `JordanMiguel\LaravelPopular\LaravelPopularServiceProvider::‌​class`

Comment: your package is working fine on my end

Comment: i think its still same, r u sure this package is working as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164160/discussion-between---and-sohel0415).

Comment: yes, just checked it, first install it, then add in the provider array and last migrate it